# grunt-shell-spawn spawn new command window

Tags: gruntjs

I want to launch a http-server in a new command prompt window as part of a grunt startup process

I'm able to use [grunt-shell-spawn](https://github.com/cri5ti/grunt-shell-spawn) to launch the the server via

```
grunt.initConfig({...
 shell:{
   httpServer:{
        command: 'http-server C:/node/MGP',
        options:{
            async:true
        }
   }
 }
```

and

```
grunt.registerTask('default',['shell:httpServer']);
```

but when I replace the command with

```
command: 'start cmd /k "http-server C:/node/MGP"',
```

or

```
command: 'start cmd /c "http-server C:/node/MGP"',
```

it launches the new command window, but does not seem to start the server - or display any indication that the server has started as one might expect.

How to execute command in new window and execute with streaming output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm use to start node server.js
Exemplo:

```
command: 'start "SERVER" node server.js'
```

if your command "http-server C:/node/MGP" its correct, just do it this:

```
command: 'start "NAME WINDOW" http-server C:/node/MGP
```

refer to start command: http://ss64.com/nt/start.html